# Reading from .txt

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve Problem 13 of project euler, which involves the sum of 100 50 digit numbers. I figured there would be a better way than the paste that whole chunk of numbers into my code. So I searched around and found that you could paste the chunk into a .txt file and read it from there.

So, how would I go about reading from a .txt file in C++ and more importantly getting the 50 digit strings individually from it?

Comment: You do know about [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("numbers.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
      getline (myfile,line);
      int i = atoi(line.c_str());
      // do here something with 'i'
      cout << i
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, well of course you can't cast 50-digit numbers into an `int`, but I guess that's another question :)

Comment: I would skip the check for `is_open` and use `while (getline(...))` instead.

Comment: @Khôi How would I get, say, the first line or the second line from the .txt?

Comment: @cortex You could put the lines (or numbers) in a `std::vector`. If pushed in the order you read them you can access the first line as `my_vector[0]` etc.

Comment: @Khôi I just started C++ a month ago so pardon my newbieness. But how would I pass each line into an element of the vector. I hadn't even touched on vectors before this so I read the official documentation :D But it doesn't mention anything about this.

Comment: @cortex You'll need to `#include <vector>` then define a vector variable `vector<string> my_vector` then put the numbers into the vector in the loop using `my_vector.push_back( i )`

Comment: @Khôi okay thanks it works now :D. Now... for the 50 digit numbers.